# Effects of straightening a bent rod of iron with and without heat

Tags: structural-engineering

I've been told that straightening a bent rod of steel (e.g., rebar) without heating it first will actually weaken it as microfibers (i.e., molecular structures) are being broken as opposed to first heating the metal which will eventually make it stronger. Is this true?

Comment: "Microfibers" should be replaced with "grain" or "crystal structure"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification DKN! I understand how important terminology is especially in technical fields!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on size, steel, amount of strain, thermomechanical history of the bar , etc.   Rebar is likely to be cold rolled, lowish carbon ( guess 0.3 %); probably tolerate 20 % strain. Any strain that does not fracture it will make it stronger. Fifty years ago rebar was mostly recycled railroad rails, high carbon might tolerate only 10 % strain. Cold strain makes it stronger and less ductile ( other than the Bauschinger effect which is complicated).

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the little history lesson r.e., the roots of rebar!

Comment: And a LOT of that rail was made at CF & I , Pueblo Co.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the metallurgy of the rebar. if the steel is low grade (i.e., containing significant amounts of embrittling contaminants like sulfur, copper or aluminum) then cold-working it like you describe will start microcracking and the straightened joint will be weakened.

Hot-working it at the right temperature will avoid this, but IMHO there's no substitute for a well-made batch of hot-rolled low carbon steel made in the US of A.

Comment: Thanks Niels! I did a little snooping and found that basalt fibre rebar appears to be a newer upgraded reinforcement bar. Although my background is mechanical engineering where I spent 32 years in aerospace, I still get a kick out of seeing skyscrapers being constructed especially the pencil-like high rises in NYC.

Comment: Had to look up basalt rebar. Looks like sales jargon for FRP ( fiberglas reinforced plastic). It is used as oil production sucker rods; very good strength but low modulus compared to steel .

Comment: Again, thank you. More research into FRP!